# How can I make pasted HTML be recognised as Blot in the editor?

Tags: javascript, quill

I am creating the editor with some default HTML to start with, at some point, a user will have to paste in form tokens that look like these: `%{token}`, by default, they are injected into the editor like this:

```html
<em class="form-token">%{name}</em>
```

I know Quill strips away classes it does not recognize so I created a Blot to help with that, but the problem is:

1. `em` tags that have no class of `form-token` get recognized as the registered Blot.
2. new `em` element pasted into the editor that looks like this: `<em class="form-token>%{name}</em>` do not get recognized, instead, they are inserted as literal text.

### What I have tried

I tried creating a matcher for the newly pasted HTML:

```js
    const editor = new Quill('#editor', {
      theme: "snow",
      modules: {
        toolbar,
      },
    });
    // matcher here
    editor.clipboard.addMatcher(Node.TEXT_NODE, function (node, delta) {
      return delta.compose(
        new Delta().retain(delta.length(), {
          italic: node.textContent?.startsWith('<em class="form-token"')
            ? true
            : null,
        })
      );
    });
```

but I do not know how to make quill convert/recognize it as the Blot I created, or even add a custom class to it, assuming I just wanted to paste in `%{name}` and allow quill to wrap it in `em` tags from the format above.

**Steps for Reproduction**

1. Visit this [pen](https://codepen.io/edmund1645/pen/NWjWbOX)
2. At the end of the JS file, paste the entire `<em>` element into the editor.

**Expected behavior**:

- The pasted HTML element should be recognized as the `FormToken` Blow that was registered.
  **Actual behavior**:
  The form element is formatted as bare text
  **Platforms**:
- Machine: MacOS Big Sur
- Browser: MS Edge Version 91.0.864.59 (Official build) (x86_64)

Include browser, operating system and respective versions

**Version**:
`1.3.6` & `1.3.7`

Answer (score 1):

### Found a solution

What I did was listen to a [paste event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/paste_event) on the editor, and then invoke the  `dangerouslyPasteHTML()` method on the clipboard module.

```js
// prevent the initial text in the clipboard from being pasted, and inert into the editor yourself
  function pasteToken(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const text = (event.clipboardData || window.clipboardData)?.getData("text");
    const selection = editor.getSelection();
    editor.clipboard.dangerouslyPasteHTML(selection.index, text, "user");
  }

    editor.root.addEventListener("paste", pasteToken, {
      capture: true,
    });
```